# Calculating Volume in different coordinate systems

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Calculate the volume enclosed from above by a sphere of radius $\\r = R$ and from below by the plane $\\z = \frac{R}{2}$:

a) Using cylindrical coordinates.

b) Using spherical coordinates.

c) Using cartesian coordinates.

I am struggling to find the correct limits of integration. This is what I have been able to come up with so far :

a) $\phi:0\to 2\pi$

$ \\ z:\frac{R}{2}\to R$

$\rho$:?

b) I do not know where to start

c) $\\z:\frac{R}{2} \to R $

I am unsure about $x,y$

Answer (score 1):

a) Cylindrical coordinates

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}R}\rho d\rho\int_{\frac R2}^{\sqrt{R^2-\rho^2}}dz$$

b) Spherical coordinates

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\sin\theta d\theta \int_{\frac R{2\cos\theta}}^{R}r^2dr$$

c) Cartesian coordinates

$$\int_{-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}R}^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}R}dx\int_{-\sqrt{ \frac{3}{4}R^2 -x^2}}^{\sqrt{ \frac{3}{4}R^2 -x^2}}dy \int_{\frac R2}^{\sqrt{ R^2 -x^2-y^2}}dz$$